# php class mysqli_query issue

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I know the issue is with the first parameter of mysqli_query, but I cant for the life of me figure out what the exact parameter should be.  I can get this working with mysql_query, but I'm trying to learn OOP and also convert to mysqli.  I would like to be able to call the connect (and disconnect eventually) when I need it, and then perform queries once it's connected.  Any assistance would be fantastic.

database.php

```
class Database{

private $db_host = "localhost"; 
private $db_user = "root"; 
private $db_pass = "root"; 
private $db_name = "db";

public function __construct(){

    $this->connect();

}

public function connect()
{
    //If database is not connected, look to connect
    if(!$this->con)
    {
        $myconn = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
        //If database is connected, select table
        if($myconn)
            {
            $seldb = mysqli_select_db($this->db_name,$myconn);
            //If database is selected, return conn
            if($seldb)
            {
                $this->con = true; 
                return true; 
            } else
            {
                return false; 
            }
        } else
        {
            return false; 
        }
    } else
    {
        return true; 
    }
}

public function disconnect()
{
if($this->con)
{
    if(mysqli_close())
    {
        $this->con = false; 
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
        return false; 
    }
}
}

}
```

school.php

```
require_once('database.php');

class Schools{

public function __construct()
{   
    $connection = new Database();
    $this->getAllSchools();
}

public function getAllSchools($connection){

$schoolsql = "SELECT SID, schoolName, schoolCity, schoolCountry, schoolRegion FROM schools ORDER BY SID";

$schoolquery = mysqli_query($connection->con, $schoolsql);
$results = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($schoolquery))
        {
           $results[] = array(
              'id' => $row['SID'],
              'name' => $row['schoolName'],
              'city' => $row['schoolCity'],
              'country' => $row['schoolCountry'],
              'region' => $row['schoolRegion']
           );
        }

        $json = json_encode($results);
        echo $json; 

}
}

$school = new Schools;
```

I know that this is where it all fails. 
    $schoolquery = mysqli_query($connection->con, $schoolsql);

I just don't know what permutation of the connection variable mysqli is really expecting from the Database class?

This set of code "works".  I know that they are security issues, but right now as I'm learning I'm just trying to get the result from the database that I'm expecting - but in the end the code structure is not what I want.  I'd prefer to have the database.php file contain a class that I can instantiate in the schools.php file.  Right now it just creates the connection and I can load that into the Schools class.  I have looked at several of the mysqli class connection issues on SO (and on Google), and tried several permutations, but I could not get the Database class option to work.

database.php

```
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_user = "root"; 
$db_pass = "root"; 
$db_name = "db";

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$mysqli) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

schools.php

```
class Schools{ 

function __construct($mysqli){
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
}

//Method to return all schools
function getAllSchools () {
    $query = "SELECT SID, schoolName, schoolCity, schoolCountry, schoolRegion FROM schools ORDER BY SID ASC";
    $results = array();
        if ($result = $this->mysqli->query($query) ) 
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $results[] = array(
                  'id' => $row['SID'],
                  'name' => $row['schoolName'],
                  'city' => $row['schoolCity'],
                  'country' => $row['schoolCountry'],
                  'region' => $row['schoolRegion']
               );
            }
        $json = json_encode($results);
        echo $json;
        $result->close();
        } else {
            echo "No results";
        }
    }
 //Method to return one school  
 function getASchool ($id) {

    $query = "SELECT SID, schoolName, schoolCity, schoolCountry, schoolRegion FROM schools WHERE SID=$id";
    $results = array();
        if ($result = $this->mysqli->query($query) ) 
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $results[] = array(
                  'id' => $row['SID'],
                  'name' => $row['schoolName'],
                  'city' => $row['schoolCity'],
                  'country' => $row['schoolCountry'],
                  'region' => $row['schoolRegion']
               );
            }
        $json = json_encode($results);
        echo $json;
        $result->close();
        } else {
            echo "No results";
        }
}   
}

$school = new Schools($mysqli);
$school->getASchool("120");
```

Comment: we can see `$this->db_host,$this->db_user...` but where is `$this->con` ?

Comment: `$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);` we can not  see where all these variables came from ? Why not use e.g. `$this->db_user` etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd prefer to have the database.php file contain a class

You have it. Mysqli is a first class class already, mind you.

> that I can instantiate in the schools.php file.

You can't have it. Instantiating a mysqli class means to create a new connection to mysql, which you surely want to do only **once** per script. So, you have to instantiate it only once and then pass this **sole instance** to other classes, like you do.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE:
There are several things that could / should be improved about the code structure, however this answer is intended to answer your direct question only.

There are two pieces:

in your `class Database`, instead of `return true;`, you need to `return $this->con`, like so:

```
class Database{

    private $db_host = "localhost"; 
    private $db_user = "root"; 
    private $db_pass = "root"; 
    private $db_name = "db";
    // Add this class variable to store con
    private $con = FALSE;

    public function __construct(){
        // Return the connection
        return $this->connect();

    }

    public function connect() {
        //If database is not connected, look to connect
        if( ! $this->con) {
            $myconn = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
            //If database is connected, select table
            if($myconn) {
                $seldb = mysqli_select_db($this->db_name,$myconn);
                //If database is selected, return conn
                if($seldb) {
                    // Assign the class variable to the connection
                    $this->con = $myconn; 
                    // Return the connection
                    return $this->con; 
                } else {
                    return false; 
                }
            } else {
                return false; 
            }
        } else {
            // Return the connection
            return $this->con; 
        }
    }
// ... the rest of your class ...

}
```

Then, in your `class Schools`, you should use a class variable for your `$connection`, like so:

```
class Schools{
    // Class variable to store your database connection
    private $connection;

    public function __construct() {   
        // Assign the connection to your class variable
        $this->connection = new Database();
        $this->getAllSchools();
    }

    public function getAllSchools($connection){
        $schoolsql = "SELECT SID, schoolName, schoolCity, schoolCountry, schoolRegion FROM schools ORDER BY SID";
        // Use the class variable to connect
        $schoolquery = mysqli_query($this->connection, $schoolsql);
        $results = array();
    // ... rest of your code
    }
}
```

**Edit** based on expanded answer:

First, your line here:
`$school = new Schools($mysqli);` - this is a form of [dependency injection](http://coderoncode.com/dependency-injection/design-patterns/programming/php/development/2014/01/06/dependency-injection-php.html).  This is something that would be good to learn / get familiar with, as it's super valuable when writing classes that "depends" on other classes.

As far as sorting out why the code below isn't doing what you expect, I'd need to see your version of the code.  NOTE that the `Database` class revisions I provided *have three* new `return` lines.  If any of those are missing, the code may not work.

The code actually should have failed with a fatal error - the function `getAllSchools` expected a parameter, but the call to it did not include that parameter.

FINALLY, the best thing to do is to learn how to debug this.  Get some troubleshooting going, by modifying your `Schools` class function, as below:

```
public function getAllSchools(){
    $schoolsql = "SELECT SID, schoolName, schoolCity, schoolCountry, schoolRegion FROM schools ORDER BY SID";
    // Use the class variable to connect
    $schoolquery = mysqli_query($this->connection, $schoolsql);
    // Is there an issue? Let's output it:
    var_dump(mysqli_error($this->connection));
    $results = array();
// ... rest of your code
}
```

Provide us with the details of the error(s), and be sure to update us with the specific code you are using that generates the error(s).

Comment: we can see `$this->db_host,$this->db_user...` but where is `$this->con` ?

Comment: @cale_b Thank you for your time and response.  Unfortunately, even with the code changes I am getting an empty array on return.  Initially I had a getJSON function making the call, but then I just started accessing the php  page by itself - and still nothing.  When I put in a mysqli_error method on the query it returns a connection error.  The funny thing is that if I just use mysql functions EVERYTHING returns as expected.  It's something to do with the first parameter of the query.  It's not the MYSQL query, because if I put it in phpMyAdmin all works just fine.

Comment: @cale_b thanks to much for your offer.  I have edited the question.  the two lower code references are the current code sets that "work" but I do no longer have a database class.  I just make the connection and load the database.php file.  I could not, for the life of me, get the mysql query to use the returned connection from the class.  I think I just do not understand enough about how the returned data from a function can be passed between/within classes??